# Customizing Asp .Net Identity External Authentication Buttons in Web Forms

Tags: css, asp.net, oauth, webforms, asp.net-identity

I am working on a project where I am using the Asp .Net Identity External login functionality. 
Using the

I have enabled the external login functionality and it shows the external login buttons on the login page. But they are plain white buttons.[image: External Login Buttons]

I want to display these buttons instead of the above-displayed buttons.[image: Customized External Login Button]

The CSS file that I am using is available [Zocial CSS file link](https://github.com/smcllns/css-social-buttons).

I have looked into the contents available at [Pretty social login buttons for ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/pretty-social-login-buttons-for-asp-net-mvc-5/) but code here is being implemented in MVC and it's not working for me on the Asp.Net Web Form.

Comment: Why can't you give those white buttons another class like `zocial facebook` or `zocial googleplus` from those "Zocial CSS file link."

Comment: Can't do that because I am using the built-in OAuth to display the external login buttons.

Comment: You can overwrite classes in a stylesheet. Those white buttons probably have a unique class or container name so you can target them specifically.

Comment: That's not working in any way. The buttons are generated based on the external service configured in the Startup.Auth.cs file of the project. The particular services incorporated in the stratup file will generate the buttons.

Comment: Changing the class name will make all of them similar.

Comment: I want to do this particualr thing in Asp.Net Web Forms (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-external-providers-in-mvc-5/)

Comment: No they don't have to be similar, you can do this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: @VDWWD you are not understanding the problem. I think you are not familiar with Asp.Net Identity and External Login Option.